# Android Beam NDEF to reader mode

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, hce, android-beam

Context: I've tried HCE in combination with reader mode and these two work like a charm.

I'm looking to provide some sense of backward compatibility with the reader mode app.

Is there a way to read or send NDEF messages over Beam from an Android 4.3 device to a reader mode enabled application?

Comment: no, there is no way.

Answer (score 1):

No, the whole point of the reader mode API (`enableReaderMode()`) is to **disable** peer-to-peer mode operation and activate only NFC reader/writer mode. As Android Beam is based on peer-to-peer mode (NFCIP1 + LLCP + SNEP) there is no way to receive or send Beam messages on a device where reader mode is active.